# ReactJS: How to overlay a component on top of another component's element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am just starting react. 
I have a component which has an input field and a button. 
There is another component which returns JSX (A blinking dot). I am importing the blinking dot component in main component and want to overlay the blinking dot on top of the input field when it is empty.

How can I achieve this? Please help me in this.

The code for this can be found in:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xmssdv

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const inputChangeHandler = event => {
    setName(event.target.value);
    console.log(name);
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
      <div className="button">
        <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
      </div>

      <Dot />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: refer to `z-index` and you need a state which controls the showing of the dot

Comment: If you have something covering the input how are you meant to access the input to type something to remove the thing that's covering it?

Comment: @DennisVash but how will i get the position of the element on which to show the blinking dot? Can you please have a look at the code. Dot goes away as you enter something in input field but how can I place it on top of the input field?

Comment: @Andy The requirement is, I want to show a blinking dot on input field to user that here to enter text. Once user enters something, the blinking dot goes to the button and starts blinking over it

Comment: The solution to your problem is you really need to go back and re-learn CSS. This issue is CSS issue alone and can be solved with CSS really easy. I won't write an answer since you clearly stated that you don't want to see any code.

Comment: @LazarMomcilovic I am stuck at it. That is why I asked for help. I know it is css and reactjs but the logic is not clicking to me so if you know then please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be easily achieved by making the following two changes: 
step 1. In `index.js` move the Dot component at the top:

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [showDot, setShowDot] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    name ? setShowDot(false) : setShowDot(true);
  }, [name])

  return (
    <div>
        { showDot ? <Dot /> : null }
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={() => setName(event.target.value)} />
      <div className="button">
        <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
         { name ? <Dot /> : null }
      </div>


    </div>
  );
}
```

step 2. In `Dot/dot.css` introduce the positioning for dot as absolute:

```
.Blink {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: blinker 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man but the issue is I have to change the position of blinking dot dynamically. It works find initially but as user enters something in input field, the blinking dot should go to the "Click Me" button. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Okay. I've made changes to the answer to meet your requirements. Try it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just one more thing. Currently the dot appears at the start of the input field. how can we place the dot at the center of the input field?